# iPhone: Upgrade to pro version using in app purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Please, I want to add a button in my app titled "Upgrade to pro Version". When the user touch this button, Some hidden buttons become unhidden.

What the code to do this, using in App purchase? All tutorials I found, discuss that you want to sell some items or other features that need a store. I don't want to create a store.

Also, how to implement restore function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't "need a store", you use `StoreKit` to do this. Start by reading the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html). Then to simplify your  IAP code you could use one of the nice wrapping frameworks people have open-sourced such as [this one by Mattt Thompson](https://github.com/mattt/CargoBay).

Comment: The pro upgrade is a 'sold item', so you should be able to follow those tutorials but make it set a flag that the app is now 'pro'. This is the 'non-consumable' product type, because it lasts forever.